# Microsoft Azure Text to Speech - Stop Recording On Button Press - StopRecognitionOnceAsync() Not Working?

Tags: javascript, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services, speech

Apologies in advance for any terminology mistakes, I'm a student and trying my hardest to be as clear as possible! and thanks in advance for any help!

I'm trying to use Azure Speech-To-Text services. I'd like the user to be able to press a start and stop button to record themselves and print out the transcription. My app will eventually be a React Frontend and Rails backend, but right now I am just trying to understand and work through the demo.

I'm confused by the documentation but was able to get things half working. However, right now it just continuously listens to the speaker and never stops.

I want to use `stopContinuousRecognitionAsync()` or `recognizer.close()` once a button is pressed, but I cannot seem to get it working. The farthest I've gotten is the result is logged only once the stop button is pressed, but it continues to listen and print out results. I've also tried using `recognizer.close() -> recognizer = undefined` but to no avail. I am guessing that due to the asynchronous behavior, it closes out the recognizer before logging a result.

The latest code I've tried is below. This result starts listening on start click and prints speech on stop, but continues to listen and log results.

```
    // subscription key and region for speech services.
    var subscriptionKey, serviceRegion;
    var authorizationToken;
    var SpeechSDK;
    var recognizer;


    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
      startRecognizeOnceAsyncButton = document.getElementById("startRecognizeOnceAsyncButton");
      subscriptionKey = document.getElementById("subscriptionKey");
      serviceRegion = document.getElementById("serviceRegion");
      phraseDiv = document.getElementById("phraseDiv");

      startRecognizeOnceAsyncButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        startRecognizeOnceAsyncButton.disabled = true;
        phraseDiv.innerHTML = "";

        // if we got an authorization token, use the token. Otherwise use the provided subscription key
        var speechConfig;
        if (authorizationToken) {
          speechConfig = SpeechSDK.SpeechConfig.fromAuthorizationToken(authorizationToken, serviceRegion.value);
        } else {
          speechConfig = SpeechSDK.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(“API_KEY”, serviceRegion.value);
        }

        speechConfig.speechRecognitionLanguage = "en-US";
        var audioConfig  = SpeechSDK.AudioConfig.fromDefaultMicrophoneInput();
        recognizer = new SpeechSDK.SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);


        recognizer.startContinuousRecognitionAsync(function () {}, function (err) {
        console.trace("err - " + err);});


        
        stopButton = document.querySelector(".stopButton")
        
        stopButton.addEventListener("click", () =>{
            console.log("clicked")
      
                recognizer.recognized = function(s,e) {
                    console.log("recognized text", e.result.text)
                }
            })
    


   
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the recognizer is conjured correctly outside of the code, there's a few things to change to get the result you want.

1. The events should be hooked to the recognizer before calling startContinuousRecognition().
2. In the stop button handler, call stop. I'd also hook the stop event outside of the start button click handler.

Quick typed changes, didn't compile. :-)

```
startRecognizeOnceAsyncButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
   startRecognizeOnceAsyncButton.disabled = true;

   //div where text is being shown
   phraseDiv.innerHTML = "";

   // The event recognized signals that a final recognition result is received.
   recognizer.recognized = function(s,e) {
      console.log("recognized text", e.result.text)
   }

   //start listening to speaker
   recognizer.startContinuousRecognitionAsync(function () {}, function (err) {
      console.trace("err - " + err);});
});

stopButton = document.querySelector(".stopButton")
        
stopButton.addEventListener("click", () =>{
   console.log("clicked");
   recognizer.stopContinuousRecongition();
};
```

Comment: thanks Ryan - i updated the code in my post to more fully show how the recognizer is being called. ri tried your solution but it gave me an error for using stopContinuousRecognitionAsync inside and outside of the start event. i'm not exactly sure why, sometimes it tells me it is not a function of the recognizer and sometimes it doesn't.